# control SOAP Logging with xml config file

Tags: c#, web-services, logging, soap, system.diagnostics

In my web-service messaging application, I have enabled Soap Logging by adding the below to my **app.config**:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net">
        <listeners>
          <add name="TraceFile"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\Dev\EvryCardManagement2014\EvryCardManagement\trace.log"/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Information"/>
      <!--add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Information"/-->
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <soapExtensionTypes>
        <add type="EvryCardManagement.SOAP.TraceExtension, EvryCardManagement" priority="1"/>
      </soapExtensionTypes>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
```

and I have a **SOAP.cs** class that intercepts the messages and copies the outbound message along with it's response into log files as below:

```
namespace EvryCardManagement.SOAP
{
    // Define a SOAP Extension that traces the SOAP request and SOAP 
    // response for the XML Web service method the SOAP extension is 
    // applied to. 

    public class TraceExtension : SoapExtension
        {
        Stream oldStream;
        Stream newStream;
        string filename;

        // Save the Stream representing the SOAP request or SOAP response into 
        // a local memory buffer. 
        public override Stream ChainStream(Stream stream)
            {
            oldStream = stream;
            newStream = new MemoryStream();
            return newStream;
            }

        // When the SOAP extension is accessed for the first time, the XML Web 
        // service method it is applied to is accessed to store the file 
        // name passed in, using the corresponding SoapExtensionAttribute.   
        public override object GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, SoapExtensionAttribute attribute)
            {
            return ((TraceExtensionAttribute)attribute).Filename;
            }

        // The SOAP extension was configured to run using a configuration file 
        // instead of an attribute applied to a specific XML Web service 
        // method. 
        public override object GetInitializer(Type WebServiceType)
            {
            // Return a file name to log the trace information to, based on the 
            // type. 
                return global::EvryCardManagement.Properties.Settings.Default.SoapLog + WebServiceType.FullName + ".log";
            }

        // Receive the file name stored by GetInitializer and store it in a 
        // member variable for this specific instance. 
        public override void Initialize(object initializer)
            {
            filename = (string)initializer;
            }

        //  If the SoapMessageStage is such that the SoapRequest or 
        //  SoapResponse is still in the SOAP format to be sent or received, 
        //  save it out to a file. 
        public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
            {
            switch (message.Stage)
                {
                case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
                    WriteOutput(message);
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
                    WriteInput(message);
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
                    break;
                }
            }

        public void WriteOutput(SoapMessage message)
            {
            newStream.Position = 0;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append,
                FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs);

            string soapString = (message is SoapServerMessage) ? "SoapResponse" : "SoapRequest";
            w.WriteLine("-----" + soapString + " at " + DateTime.Now);
            w.Flush();
            Copy(newStream, fs);
            w.Close();
            newStream.Position = 0;
            Copy(newStream, oldStream);
            }

        public void WriteInput(SoapMessage message)
            {
            Copy(oldStream, newStream);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append,
                FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs);

            string soapString = (message is SoapServerMessage) ?
                "SoapRequest" : "SoapResponse";
            w.WriteLine("-----" + soapString +
                " at " + DateTime.Now);
            w.Flush();
            newStream.Position = 0;
            Copy(newStream, fs);
            w.Close();
            newStream.Position = 0;
            }

        void Copy(Stream from, Stream to)
            {
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(from);
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(to);
            writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            writer.Flush();
            }
        }

    // Create a SoapExtensionAttribute for the SOAP Extension that can be 
    // applied to an XML Web service method.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class TraceExtensionAttribute : SoapExtensionAttribute
        {

        private string filename = "C:\\Evry Card Management\\SOAP Logs\\Soaplog.txt";
        private int priority;

        public override Type ExtensionType
            {
            get { return typeof(TraceExtension); }
            }

        public override int Priority
            {
            get { return priority; }
            set { priority = value; }
            }

        public string Filename
            {
            get
                {
                return filename;
                }
            set
                {
                filename = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

and this all works fine and dandy.

My issue is that once we go live, we will only want to log soap messages if there is a problem, so I need to be able to control whether logging is enabled by setting a value in application settings.

So how can I set it up so that if I don't have that setting set to true in my application properties..settings then the logging will be disabled?

Comment: Isn't this just a question about how to read a value from a config file?

Comment: @JohnSaunders well, I can do that, but where would I write code to disable the logging process?

Comment: There is no way to turn off a SoapExtension, so you would have to write that code in the extension. Just don't log.

Comment: OTOH, changing a setting in web.config will cause the AppDomain to recycle. This would mean your `GetInitializer` and `Initialize` methods will be called again. That would be a good place to retrieve the log settings. You'll then have to enforce them on each `ProcessMessage` call.

Comment: @JohnSaunders If you would suggest that as an answer I can accept it...